# Meaning of "Give me some credit" in "Anne of Green Gables"

Tags: meaning, l-m-montgomery, anne-of-green-gables

In *Anne of Green Gables* by L. M. Montgomery, Marilla criticizes Anne for talking too much:

> "Well, I guess I'll light the lamp and get to work," said Marilla. "I see plainly that you don't want to hear what Miss Stacy had to say. You're 
>   more interested in the sound of your own tongue than in anything else."
>
> "Oh, indeed, Marilla, I do want to hear it," cried Anne contritely. " I won't say another word — not one. I know I talk too much, but I am really trying to overcome it, and although I say far too much, yet if you only knew how many things I want to say and don't, you'd **give me some credit** for it. Please tell me, Marilla."

What does Anne mean by "give me some credit"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Chenmunka It's a question about the meaning of a phrase in a work of literature, and therefore seems *on-topic* here, regardless of its quality and of whether or not other SE sites would also accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Anne is saying that she is been trying to talk less and that if Marilla had been aware of her efforts, she would have expressed appreciation or possibly given her praise for it (=given her credit for it).

For another example of "giving someone credit" in a different context, see [Give me credit](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/spanish/features/the-english-we-speak/ep-150818) on BBC Learning English (18 August 2015).